# Accessing nested List xml elements formed during JAX WS implementation of Webservice

Tags: java, xml, web-services

I have automatically generated java classes, generated from WSDL after wsimport command. This is basically nested list of elements one inside the other. It is converted into list because in xsd of the WSDL, these elements are defined as "unbound".I want to access all elements inside the parent innermost element address with the help of getter method in java.

Here are the exmaple of how my xml (generated java classes) looks like

Person parent class contains following property.

```
List<Address> address
List<PersonIdentification> identification
List<ContactMethod> contact
List<PersonName> name
```

Address inside Person contains following property.

```
String previousAddressLine1
String CurrentAddressLine1
List<Address> address
```

Address inside Address contains following property.

```
String addressLineOne
String postCode
String city
```

I want to access all the elements of innermost Address element using java getter and setter method.

Be aware that  may occur any number of times and I want to get value for all occurrences.

Please help!

Comment: If I get your question correctly you wanted to access all the addresses stored in person object. In order to do this you can use the code like - `for(Address address : person.getAddress){ address.getAddressLineOne(); }`

Comment: Will this fetch all the Address property inside Address i.e all the address inside the third layer, considering Person as the first layer ?

Comment: I think Person class is inheriting properties from its parent class. Is address property inheritable (not private in Person's parent class)? So there is only two levels: `1. Person  contains Address or 2. Person's Parent class contains Address`. If this is the case then you can access all the address by the code sample mentioned in above comment.